# How to correctly generate date column sequence using two tables?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table in Snowflake:

Table 1

```
id | start     | end        | price
1  | 2020-01-01| 2020-01-03 | 100
2  | 2020-01-05| 2020-01-08 | 200
```

Table 2

```
utc_date  
2000-01-01
.
.
.   
2021-01-01
```

Desired Output Table 3:

```
id | utc_date  | price
1  | 2020-01-01|100
1  | 2020-01-02|100
1  | 2020-01-03|100
2  | 2020-01-05|200
2  | 2020-01-06|200
2  | 2020-01-07|200
2  | 2020-01-08|200
```

I am thinking of doing a join but I am not sure if that will work. Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 1):

a join should work:

```
select t1.id , t2.utc_date , t1.price
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
 on t2.utc_date between t1.start and t1.end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `cross join`.

```
create or replace table table1 (id integer, startdt date, enddt date, price  number(15,2));

insert into table1 values 
    (1, '2020-01-01', '2020-01-03', 100),
    (2, '2020-01-05', '2020-01-08', 100);

select * from table1;
+----+------------+------------+--------+
| ID | STARTDT    | ENDDT      |  PRICE |
|----+------------+------------+--------|
|  1 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03 | 100.00 |
|  2 | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-08 | 100.00 |
+----+------------+------------+--------+


create or replace table table2 (utc_date date);
insert into table2 values
    ('2019-12-31'),
    ('2020-01-01'),
    ('2020-01-02'),
    ('2020-01-03'),
    ('2020-01-04'),
    ('2020-01-05'),
    ('2020-01-06'),
    ('2020-01-07'),
    ('2020-01-08'),
    ('2020-01-09'),
    ('2020-01-10');

select id, utc_date, price from table1 t1 cross join table2 t2
    where t2.utc_date >= t1.startdt and t2.utc_date <= t1.enddt;

+----+------------+--------+
| ID | UTC_DATE   |  PRICE |
|----+------------+--------|
|  1 | 2020-01-01 | 100.00 |
|  1 | 2020-01-02 | 100.00 |
|  1 | 2020-01-03 | 100.00 |
|  2 | 2020-01-05 | 100.00 |
|  2 | 2020-01-06 | 100.00 |
|  2 | 2020-01-07 | 100.00 |
|  2 | 2020-01-08 | 100.00 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option save some I/O and create the 'date' table in memory using [generator() function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html) . I've found benefit in reducing I/O at any cost useful when dealing with extremely large datasets (the ones that spit out 1002 errors)

```
WITH CTE_MY_DATE AS (
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,  1*SEQ4(), (CURRENT_DATE()-18000  ) ) AS MY_DATE
FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => (365000 ) )) -- Number of days after reference date in previous line
) ,data as ( 
 SELECT 1 ID   , '2020-01-01' start_date,'2020-01-03' end_date ,100 val UNION SELECT  2 ID   , '2020-01-05' start_date, '2020-01-08' end_date ,200 val)   

SELECT  data.id, my_date, val FROM data 
INNER JOIN cte_my_date on cte_my_date.my_date between start_date and end_date
```

[image]